# Include a module in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to include a verilog module into another file. How do I include it in the code and how do I compile the code to include the header file? Is it like in c?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. A basic example can include them both in the same file as shown on [page 4 of verilog in a day](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day4.html).
2. All files in the same folder should be automatically found.
3. Include them [as shown in Hello_World_Program_Output](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/first1.html#Hello_World_Program_Output) or Example below.
4. Advanced workflows can have files.f listing the verilog or config files specifying include directories.

Include example for (3):

```
`include "folder/sub.sv"
module top;
  sub sub_i(
    .a(),
    .b()
    ...
```

The file extension `.v` is used for verilog compilation, your compiler should use the latest standard up to Verilog 2005. The `.sv` extension is for SystemVerilog. Which replaced Verilog in 2009. The file extension causes the compiler to switch to SystemVerilog.

Comment: Is it allowed to have `include inside the module (say along with parameter declarations)?