# Dependency on Verilog libs

Tags: scala, hardware, verilog, hdl, chisel

Is it possible to depend on some already coded Verilog libs in Scala Chisel?

If not that looks to me like a feature as major as Scala's Java retro-compatibility, which made the success of Scala in the soft world.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may include some external module as a [blackbox](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/manual.html):

> 12 BlackBox
>
> Black boxes allow users to define interfaces to circuits
> defined outside of Chisel. The user defines:
>
> a module as a subclass of BlackBox and an io field with the interface.
> For example, one could define a simple ROM blackbox as:
>
> ```
> class RomIo extends Bundle { 
>   val isVal = Bool(INPUT) 
>   val raddr = UInt(INPUT,  32) 
>   val rdata = UInt(OUTPUT, 32) 
> } 
>  
> class Rom extends BlackBox { 
>   val io = new RomIo() 
> }
> ```

Unfortunatelly, I didn't find any tool to generate blackboxes from `.v` files. It seems that you have to define all required types/interfaces by yourself (using `Bundle`). About importing - all `.v` files in the same folder are automatically [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661868/include-a-module-in-verilog) (so you can just put your `library.v` right next to generated `.v` files), but sometimes you may need to manually add some more complex includes into generated `.v` files. So it's not much handy yet.