# iverilog syntax for include?

Tags: verilog, hdl, iverilog

I'm trying to include a Verilog file (alu.v) in my main file (cpu.v). Both files are in the same directory.

```
'include "alu.v"

 module cpu();
 ...
 ...
 endmodule
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error.

```
cpu.v:1 syntax error
I give up
```

I don't see how the include statement is wrong. I'm sure my syntax is correct like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661868/include-a-module-in-verilog).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be so sure! Proof you mess with something, it does not work.

The preprocessor directives in Verilog begin with a **back-tick** (**`**) not an apostrophe (**'**).

Try:

```
`include "alu.v"
```

Instead of:

```
'include "alu.v"
```